# Automating authentication with Watir

Tags: ruby, automation, watir

I've searched and searched for this, but I can't seem to get this automation to work. Having used all of the [basic authentication code](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Basic+Authentication) on the OpenQA site, I still cannot get the authentication box to work.

I'm using IE8, with a website that has HTTPS enabled.

By using Watir I'm able to open IE to the correct page, but nothing I try allows me to enter any content into the login form.

Here is the code I've whittled it down to:

```
require 'watir'

url = 'https://thewebsite.com' 
@username = 'myusername'
@password = 'mypassword' 

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto url
sleep 5 
Watir.autoit.WinWait('Blank Page')
Watir.autoit.Send(@username)
Watir.autoit.Send('{TAB}')
Watir.autoit.Send(@password)
Watir.autoit.Send('{ENTER}')
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, or links? A lot of the information I've found on the OpenQA site seems quite out of date.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide us an example of a public site that has such authentication?  Obviously in order to automate this section we don't need to be able to actually access the site, but if we can get the authentication dialog, enter data and click the button (even if our credentials are rejected) it would be good enough.  Without an example it's hard for people to experiment or debug the existing code.

Comment: Firstly, what version of Watir are you using?  Secondly, what exactly happens when you try the code you gave above.  Knowing what you tried is good, but without details on what happens (such as any error messages) still leaves us with not enough useful info to figure out where your approach is going wrong on you.

Comment: Not sure if you'll be able to get onto this site (you may have to be on the network) https://evolve.warwickshire.nhs.uk/ArdenDev

Comment: Watir version 2.02. Ruby 1.9.2p290. 

IE Opens, page loads, nothing is inputted into the boxes. This is the resulting error in the console: 

...evolve.rb:14:in '<main>' : undefined method 'autoit' for Watir:Module(NoMethodError)

Now I may be being stupid, I've installed autoit, though I fear I may have left out a vital part..

Comment: Have you tried authenticating on the url such as 
    hhtp://myusername/mypassword@thewebsite.com

Comment: Josh - does the username/password even open in a popup, or is it built into the web page??

Comment: I've tried the htp://myusername/mypassword@thewebsite.com method and sadly it fails. 

Adam, I'll link a screenshot to it when I'm at work tomorrow.

Comment: @Josh, When you are making that screenshot try a few things.   Firstly, can you drag around the window that pops up?  can you drag it completely outside the browser or is it limited to the browser window (e.g. can you drag it over to sit on top of your desktop with the browser NOT maximized..)  Secondly, can you see the contents of the popup if you use the developer tools?

Comment: Can be dragged, limited to window, can't select with dev tools. Tried with both Chrome and IE. 

Screenshot (hosted on Dropbox) http://lncn.eu/u267

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [RAutomation](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation) instead of autoit?

Comment: Can you give me an example of simple authentication?

Comment: I never had to deal with popups, so I do not have any example code. I have just heard that watir is no longer using autoit, but rautomation for dealing with popups.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the url with user and pass in it? like url = 'https://username:password@thewebsite.com', you can try visiting the url manually in a browser, if it works manually it should work in your script too.

Answer (score 0):

I came here having the same problem, although it looks like the answer is different due to the latest version of Watir and watir-webdriver.  I'll show what worked for me using:

```
watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
watir-classic (3.6.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
```

Watir doesn't have autoit built in any more and it looks like the other suggestion I found (`require 'watir/ie'`) doesn't work any more either.  In the spirit of solving this with the original tech requested:

Make sure after installation AutoIT has been registered with windows.
Go to the AutotIT dll (installed with the rautomation gem mentioned above, think Watir installed this)

```
cd C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rautomation-0.8.0\ext\AutoItX
regsvr32 AutoItX3.dll
```

Then the code below should work

```
require 'watir'
require 'win32ole'

$b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
begin
    $b.goto( 'http://10.254.157.34:8383/mywebsite/stuff.html');
rescue Exception => e
    puts "Trapped Error, expecting modal dialog exception"
    puts e.backtrace 
    puts "Continuing"
end

login_title = "Windows Security" #For Windows 7, dialog title for anything else
username = "myuser"
password = "mypassword"

sleep 1 #Just in case
au3 = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
win_exists = au3.WinWait(login_title, "", 5)    

if (win_exists > 0)
    au3.WinActivate(login_title)
    au3.Send('!u')
    au3.Send(username)
    au3.Send('{TAB}')
    au3.Send(password)
    au3.Send('{ENTER}')
end
```